# PortletSession using JSF Liferay Portlets

Tags: jsf-2, liferay, portlet

I am developing a JSF 2 Portlet, but i need get global session variable.

The request works fine with:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    PortletRequest request = (PortletRequest) facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest();
```

But the session is null:

```
PortletSession session = request.getPortletSession(false);
```

if put this code in liferay-portlet.xml file works fine, but i can't do IPC: Inter Portlet Comunication

```
<!-- Portlet session -->
    <private-request-attributes>false</private-request-attributes>
    <private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>
```

How i get and set variables session without use the last code?

Thanks

Today i i tried with this:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
PortletRequest request = (PortletRequest) facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest(); 
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(request); 
HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession(true); 
System.out.println(session.getAttribute("XXXX"));
```

but is null

Comment: I don't do portlets, but shouldn't you be passing `true` as *create* argument? `getPortletSession(true)`. That would logically make more sense.

Comment: where did you set the attribute? please provide that snippet.

Comment: You should really avoid using the session and session sharing if possible. There are many better solutions to sharing session data that I've enumerated here: https://community.liferay.com/blogs/-/blogs/how-can-i-share-session-data-across-portlets-in-liferay-. More importantly, **[using `<private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>` with Liferay Faces has been known to cause memory leaks](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-2094), so avoid using it with JSF applications**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Warning: Using `<private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>` with Liferay Faces has been known [to cause memory leaks](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-2094). Use at your own risk!

I solved my problem configuring liferay-portlet.xml

1.) I changed the liferay-portlet.xml only with:

```
<private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>
```

2.) In the Java Class i created method:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
PortletRequest request = (PortletRequest) facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest();
PortletSession session = request.getPortletSession(false);
```

If you get session attributes

```
session.getAttribute("XXXXXX",PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

If you set session attributes

```
session.setAttribute("NAME","VALUE",PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Warning: Using `<private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>` with Liferay Faces has been known [to cause memory leaks](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-2094). Use at your own risk!

Reorder it will work!

```
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>distribution</portlet-name>
    <icon>/icon.png</icon>
    <instanceable>false</instanceable>
    <private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>
            ...
            ...
            ...
            ...
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options :

1) When you set the attribute in the PortletSession, use this method public void setAttribute(String name, Object value, int scope), where scope should be `PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE`

When you do this, please change this to your `liferay-portlet.xml`

```
<private-request-attributes>false</private-request-attributes>
<private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>
```

#### Warning: Using `<private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>` with Liferay Faces has been known [to cause memory leaks](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-2094). Use at your own risk!

2) Use `HttpSession` instead of `PortletSession`, in order to get the `HttpSession`, please use `PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(portletRequest)` and from the httpServletRequest, get the HttpSession.

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Comment: When i want get the session attribute this is null, using HttpSession instead of PortletSession

Comment: Get the attribute from HttpSession only if you set in the http session. Did you try option 1?

Comment: #2 is not likely to work in Liferay 7.0+; instead try a solution here: https://community.liferay.com/blogs/-/blogs/how-can-i-share-session-data-across-portlets-in-liferay-

Answer (score 0):

Christy's 2nd option worked for me. When i set

```
<private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>
```

it causes my portlet deploy fail. There was an error while parsing xml file.

I dont know why. Liferay Version 6.1.1